# Exception not serializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this exception class:

```
[Serializable]
public class LoginException : Exception
{
    public LoginError LoginError { get; private set; }

    public LoginException(LoginError loginError)
    {
        this.LoginError = loginError;
    }

    public LoginException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            this.LoginError = (LoginError)info.GetValue("LoginError", typeof(LoginError));
        }
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);

        if (info != null)
        {
            info.AddValue("LoginError", this.LoginError);
        }
    }
}
```

When I return this exception from my WebApi action, I get the following exception:

`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'LoginError' was not found. at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue(String name, Type type)`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe the private flag in the LoginError property is the problem?

Comment: I think you can not have a public property with a private setter `LoginError`

Comment: What is it `LoginError`?

Comment: @Denis It's an enum. I still get the error is the property is public (get & set).

Comment: I'm missing a public contructor without parameters aswell (it is needed for serialization)

Comment: Eventhough it doesn't solve the problem: you're not calling base for the serialization constructor.

Comment: When I add a paramteterless constructor all call base for serialization constructore. I get an exception "Member 'ClassName' was not found"